# How to include image to pdf document?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdfpages

I would like to include pdf as background for a specific page and add a picture in the left bottom corner.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure} \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}[      
            every node/.style={anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt},
            x=1mm, y=1mm,
            ]   
            \node (fig1) at (0,0)
            {\includepdf{pdfile}};
            \node (fig2) at (3,3)
            {\includegraphics[scale=0.21]{example-image-b}};  
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The new shipout hook mechanism could be used (requires LaTeX format `2020/10/01`):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(0,0){\raisebox{-\paperheight}{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{example-image-b}}}}%
    Dummy Text.
\end{document}
```

Coordinate `(0,0)` is the upper left page corner. Hence `\raisebox{-\paperheight}{...}`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `fancyhdr` package and put the image in a fancyfoot on the bottom left. Take a look at my code - there are some slight changes to your code and I hope this is still okay. I have inserted a lot of comments to make it more comprehensible. If you don't want to use the fancy pagestyle anymore, you can change it to plain (optional).

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove the line in the header that comes with fancyhdr
\fancyhf{} % remove page numbers on the bottom center
\fancyfoot[L]{ %fancyfoot with the argument "L" means anything you want will be put at the bottom left. Change the "L" to "R" if you want it to be on the bottom right
    \begin{tikzpicture}[      
        every node/.style={anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt},
        x=1mm, y=1mm,
        ]   
        \node (fig2) at (3,3)
        {\includegraphics[scale=0.21]{example-image-b}};  
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\fancypagestyle{plain}{ % optional: define a plain fancyheader / fancyfoot if you don't want to use the fancy pagestyle for certain pdf files
    \fancyhf{}
    }

\begin{document}
    \includepdfset{pages=-, pagecommand=\thispagestyle{fancy}} % fancy page style with image on the bottom left
    
    \includepdf{\detokenize{document.pdf}}
    
    \includepdfset{pages=-, pagecommand=\thispagestyle{plain}} % plain page style without image on the bottom left
    
    \includepdf{\detokenize{document.pdf}}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: if i change the `\node (fig2) at (7,7)`, the position is not changing. please advise. ie i want to move the image according to user preferences

Comment: you can use `\hspace{1cm}` or `\hspace{-1cm}` before the `\node` of the image to align the image horizontally on the left or on the right (value 1 cm can be changed as desired). I am not sure about how to align it vertically though. Probably changing the height of the footer would work but I don't have an idea of how to do this right now. But it is better to a new question about this than asking in the comments.